# MSVCRT: Where is the implement (source code) of sin, cos et al?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-c++, msvcrt

I wonder where the implemention of basic trigonometric functions can be found in the Visual C++ CRT.

*Find in files* for *"sin"* in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\crt` shows the definition in `math.h` but nothing more (except a mention in the `EXPORTS` section of some def file).

To the best of my knowledge, `sin` is not a keyword that the compiler translates itself to machine code. So there must be an implementation somewhere, even if that implementation boils down to some straight assembly code.

What am I missing here? *Where'z teh codez?*

**EDIT:** Obviously, I was not clear enough: I'm looking for the source code, not compiled lib or dll

Comment: next time you wonder: build an exe/dll using the function, then use Dependency Walker to find out. It's a must have tool. Or use Dumpbin like Mark showed.

Comment: @stijn: depends.exe do'esn't show the source code!

Comment: The Microsoft C runtime isn't Open Source, here is the math header implementation for the GNU C runtime though: http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=math;h=dfc4f1d1e368d62a9f7fb558ca47e3ee23c7e52e;hb=refs/heads/master

Comment: Most of it is installed in the directory I mentioned though. Apparently not all of it.

Comment: Microsoft purchased it from Intel, without being able to obtain the right to redistribute the source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's in MSVCR90.DLL:

```
C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_...>dumpbin /exports msvcr90.dll | findstr sin
         74   48 0007ABA0 _CIasin = __CIasin
         84   52 0007B5C0 _CIsin = __CIsin
         85   53 0007AF38 _CIsinh = __CIsinh
        159   9D 000236AB __get_flsindex = ___get_flsindex
        160   9E 000236AB __get_tlsindex = ___get_flsindex
        177   AF 0007CE73 __libm_sse2_asin = ___libm_sse2_asin
        178   B0 0007D2C1 __libm_sse2_asinf = ___libm_sse2_asinf
        192   BE 0007FE7C __libm_sse2_sin = ___libm_sse2_sin
        193   BF 00080039 __libm_sse2_sinf = ___libm_sse2_sinf
        696  2B7 0002E27A _mbsinc = __mbsinc
        697  2B8 0002E24E _mbsinc_l = __mbsinc_l
       1211  4BA 0007AB60 asin = _asin
       1349  544 0007B580 sin = _sin
       1350  545 0007AF20 sinh = _sinh
```

#### Update:

The source isn't provided.  The library supplying the functions  in the CRT source provided seems to be in `crt\src\intel\mt_lib\tran.lib`:

```
C:\...\crt\src\intel\mt_lib> lib /list tran.lib
    :   :   :
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\SELF_X86\crt\prebuild\build\INTEL\mt_obj\_sincosf_sse2_.obj
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\SELF_X86\crt\prebuild\build\INTEL\mt_obj\_sincos_sse2_.obj
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\SELF_X86\crt\prebuild\build\INTEL\mt_obj\_sinf_sse2_.obj
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\SELF_X86\crt\prebuild\build\INTEL\mt_obj\_sin_sse2_.obj
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\SELF_X86\crt\prebuild\build\INTEL\mt_obj\_tanf_sse2_.obj
f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\SELF_X86\crt\prebuild\build\INTEL\mt_obj\_tan_sse2_.obj
    :   :   :
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm looking for the source code, not the compiled code.

Answer (score 1):

It's in libc.  If you are building statically, its in libc.lib.  If you are building dynamically, then its in msvcrt.dll

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm looking for the source code, not the compiled code

Comment: @Serge-appTranslator stupid question: did you install the CRT source?